# Outlook Rule: Filter e-mails from long domains

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Recently been innundated with a lot of spam email, all coming from senders with really long domain names. (of the format @{15+ characters}.{20+ characters}.net)

Of course, the bots have been getting smarter, so the domain randomly changes for each email, varying by a couple digits/characters each time.

Is there a way in outlook/hotmail to filter out emails with a domain over a certain length?

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to filter out or block the domain with long domain name by Outlook client build-in feature.

As a workaround, you could block an entire domain and all its subdomains or block country specific top-level domains. Please refer to the following article for more detailed information:

[Using wildcards to block Junk E-mail domains - MSOutlook.info](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/block-junk-email-domain)

Hope the info could help you.